# Extjs modern transparent background image and camera preview for mobile app are dark with cordova plugin qrscanner

Tags: cordova, extjs, cordova-plugins

We are developing a mobile app using extjs modern toolkit 7.4 and we use cordova to build the native apps (ios & android). We also use cordova plugins, currently we have an issue with the [cordova-plugin-qrscanner](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner) that requires the developers to bring the native camera preview in front of the cordova app's webview. In other words we need to hide or set transparent all html elements that are in front of the camera preview.

We achieve this by running `Ext.Viewport.hide();` that hides the entire app and the camera preview is shown normally. Then I show an Ext.Dialog that has a transparent image as background and some items (2 buttons and a titlebar). **The problem then is that the whole view gets a gray shade layer** and the **camera preview is dark** both for android and ios.

The view is like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Dialog', {
        bodyStyle: 'background-color: transparent; padding: 0; border-width: 0; background-image: url(resources/images/qr-scanner.png); background-size: 100% 100%;',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Scan_QR',
            titleAlign: 'center',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'action',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-times',
                align: 'left',
                listeners: {...}
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            docked: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            padding: {
                bottom: '30'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'action round',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-bolt',
                align: 'middle',
                padding: {
                    top: '15',
                    left: '15',
                    right: '15',
                    bottom: '15'
                },
                listeners: {...}
            }, {
                xtype: 'spacer',
                width: '30'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'action round',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-sync',
                align: 'middle',
                padding: {
                    top: '15',
                    left: '15',
                    right: '15',
                    bottom: '15'
                },
                listeners: {...}
            }]
        }]
    });
```

The result is something like this:

[camera preview with scanner window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rATXz.jpg)

I have tried to change the Zindex of viewport but didn't seem promising. What seems that has to be fixed is the the opacity of the dom element of the dialog that I show. A config that I may have missed.

Comment: Did you try to set `modal: false`?

Comment: Only issue is in android 10 (android 11+ is fine), dark mode makes camera preview black. This was also an issue before the modal: false fix.

Comment: The dark mode black camera preview was a cordova plugin related issue and a fix is described here: https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/332